# R: sorting a matrix?

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have following R matrix:

```
> matrix
   8 4 3 5 7 2 1 6 ...
8  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
4  1 0 1 1 0 2 0 0
3  5 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
5  0 0 1 0 0 3 0 0
7  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2  3 4 1 0 0 7 0 0
1  8 0 4 0 0 0 8 0
6  9 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
...
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 23 rows ]
```

**Question**: Is it possible to sort the matrix rows and columns, so that

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
1 ...
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
...
```

?

I only found [this here](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/BioPhysConnectoR/html/mat.sort.html) and wondered if there is not better native option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are refering to the row and column names of the matrix such as in this example matrix

```
m<-matrix(scan(text="
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 1 0 2 0 0
5 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 3 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 4 1 0 0 7 0 0
8 0 4 0 0 0 8 0
9 0 1 0 0 0 0 0"), ncol=8)
colnames(m)<-c(8,4,3,5,7,2,1,6)
rownames(m)<-c(8,4,3,5,7,2,1,6)
```

You could sort the rows and columns by name with

```
m[, sort(colnames(m))][sort(rownames(m)), ]
```

Row and column names are always treated as strings. So if you have larger numbers, you may want to convert to numeric before sorting: `sort(as.numeric(colnames(m)))`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `order()` function and pick up rows and columns by positions:

```
mat[order(rownames(mat)),order(colnames(mat))]

#  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#1 8 0 4 0 0 0 0 8
#2 0 7 1 4 0 0 0 3
#3 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 5
#4 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 1
#5 0 3 1 0 0 0 0 0
#6 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 9
#7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#8 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```